# how to detect if the barcode is for Weight Scale Item

Tags: barcode

I wonder how we can detect if a barcode that is read by barcode reader is related to an items that is sold by weight or a regular item ( in Ean-13 or other formats) ? is there any part of code that shows that it is a weighted Item?

Answer (score 2):

Barcodes are just strings of characters (mostly numbers and letters) and most barcode readers/scanners do not indicate the type of barcode.  They just send the value.  But some values, such as an EAN13, have embedded check digits that can be used to auto-discriminate.  For example, if you see a 13-digit number and calculate the mod10 check digit over the first 12 digits and it matches the 13th digit, you can be fairly certain you have an EAN13.

Alternatively, if you have control over the creation of the barcodes, you can use GS1 application identifiers to prefix each value. (GS1 barcodes can actually contain multiple values in a single symbol.)  See https://www.gs1.org/standards/barcodes/application-identifiers?lang=en for more information on the standard ids.  Application ids are routinely used in logistics but are fairly rare in retail channels.